# how to add stylesheet and jquery to joomla 3.x module

Tags: javascript, css, joomla, module

I create a basic module for joomla 3.
this is my file structure .

```
mod_helloworld.php
mod_helloworld.xml
helper.php
tmpl/default.php
css/style.css
js/javascript.js
```

this is my source mod_helloworld.php file

```
<?php 
// no direct access
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
// Include the syndicate functions only once
require_once( dirname(__FILE__).'/helper.php' );
?>
```

now I want to add stylesheet and javascript to this module .I change mod_helloworld.php to 
this :

```
<?php 
// no direct access
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
// Include the syndicate functions only once
require_once( dirname(__FILE__).'/helper.php' );
$doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addStyleSheet( 'css/style.css' );
$doc->addScript('js/javascript.js');
?>
```

but this not working for me.
please help me.

Comment: Try with full path like : $doc->addScript("http://www.example.com/js/myscript.js");

Comment: @JitendraKhatri - No, don't use full paths. This isn't recommended

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use JUir::root() which will automatically define the root of your site for you. So use the following:

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addStyleSheet( JUri::root() . 'modules/mod_helloworld/css/style.css' );
$doc->addScript( JUri::root() . 'modules/mod_helloworld/js/javascript.js' );
```

Hope this helps